# Screenshots not attached to Extent Reports C#, DotNet CORE, Specflow

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, selenium-webdriver, specflow, extentreports

I am trying to add screenshots to my extent reports.My Html reports are created fine but for some reason i am not able to attach screenshot. Could someone please help ? Below is my configuration

The problem is with attaching the screenshots to the reports as I could see the screenshots being created in the directory.

```
using System;
using TechTalk.SpecFlow;
using TechTalk.SpecFlow.Bindings;
using AventStack.ExtentReports;
using AventStack.ExtentReports.Gherkin.Model;
using AventStack.ExtentReports.Reporter;
using SbAutomation.ExtensionMethods;
using NUnit.Framework;
using NUnit.Framework.Interfaces;
using SbAutomation.Shared;
using OpenQA.Selenium;

namespace SbAutomation.Common
{
    [Binding]
    public class Hooks
    {
        private static ExtentTest _feature;
        private static ExtentTest _scenario;
        public static AventStack.ExtentReports.ExtentReports Extent;

        [BeforeTestRun]
        public static void ConfigureReport()
        {
        }

        [BeforeFeature]
        public static void CreateFeature(FeatureContext featureContext)
        {
            _feature = Extent.CreateTest<Feature>(featureContext.FeatureInfo.Title);
        }

        [BeforeScenario]
        public static void CreateScenario(ScenarioContext _scenarioContext)
        {
            _scenario = _feature.CreateNode<Scenario>(_scenarioContext.ScenarioInfo.Title);
        }

        [AfterStep]
        public static void InsertReportingSteps()
        {
            switch (ScenarioStepContext.Current.StepInfo.StepDefinitionType)
            {
                case StepDefinitionType.Given:
                    _scenario.StepDefinitionGiven();
                    break;

                case StepDefinitionType.Then:
                    _scenario.StepDefinitionThen();
                    break;

                case StepDefinitionType.When:
                    _scenario.StepDefinitionWhen();
                    break;
            }
        }

        [AfterScenario]
        public static void FlushExtent()
        {
            var status = TestContext.CurrentContext.Result.Outcome.Status;
            var stackTrace = "<pre>" + TestContext.CurrentContext.Result.StackTrace + "</pre>";
            var errorMessage = TestContext.CurrentContext.Result.Message;

            if (status == TestStatus.Failed)
            {
                string screenShotPath = GetScreenShot.Capture("screenshot-name");
                _scenario.Log(Status.Fail, stackTrace + errorMessage);
                //_feature.Log(Status.Fail, "Snapshot below: " + _feature.AddScreenCaptureFromBase64String(screenShotPath));
                _scenario.Info("Failure", MediaEntityBuilder.CreateScreenCaptureFromPath(screenShotPath).Build());
            }
        }

    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Have you been able to fix that? I have the same problem still with the Core.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (status == TestStatus.Failed)
            {
                string screenShotPath = GetScreenShot.Capture("screenshot-name");
                _scenario.Log(Status.Fail, stackTrace + errorMessage);
                //_feature.Log(Status.Fail, "Snapshot below: " + _feature.AddScreenCaptureFromBase64String(screenShotPath));
                _scenario.Log(Status.Info, "Screenshot: ", MediaEntityBuilder.CreateScreenCaptureFromPath(".\\" + screenShotPath).Build());
            }
```

Comment: I see changes only in this line

`_scenario.Log(Status.Info, "Screenshot: ", MediaEntityBuilder.CreateScreenCaptureFromPath(".\\" + screenShotPath).Build());`

It doesn't work though.

Comment: I am using
test.Log(Status.Info, "Screenshot: ", MediaEntityBuilder.CreateScreenCaptureFromPath(".\\" + screenShotPath).Build()); and it is working fine

Answer (score 0):

Try using Extent report version 3. There are some issues in Version 4.

Also, check whether this variable `string screenShotPath` is returning the full path of your image including the extensions like .png or .jpeg.

Comment: i actually use DotNet CORE version `<PackageReference Include="ExtentReports.Core" Version="1.0.2" />`

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to embedd the screenshots as Base64 String directly into ExtentReport HTML file instead of producing physical files and attaching them to a report. The problem is that based on your OS security and browser configuration, many browsers just deny to display these "referenced" screenshots and you see just nothing.
Embedding of screenshots solves this problem and makes reports even more portable.

Try something like this:

```
string encodedImage = ((ITakesScreenshot)driver).GetScreenshot().AsBase64EncodedString;

_scenario.Log(Status.Info, "Screenshot: ", MediaEntityBuilder.CreateScreenCaptureFromBase64String(encodedImage ).Build());
```

Answer (score 0):

```
string img = ((ITakesScreenshot)driver).GetScreenshot().AsBase64EncodedString;

_scenario.Log(Status.Info, "Screenshot: ", MediaEntityBuilder.CreateScreenCaptureFromBase64String(img).Build());
```

this works for me

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).